# how to pass the parameters to the urlconnection in java/android?

Tags: java, android, url, stream

i can establish a connection using HttpUrlConnection. my code below.

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URL action_url = new URL(actionUrl);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) action_url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("userType", "2");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME);
DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
String content = "username=username1&password=password11";
Log.v(TAG, "content: " + content);
ds.writeBytes(content);
ds.flush();
ds.close();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();//**getting filenotfound exception here.**
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
str1.append(line);
Log.v(TAG, "line:" + line);
}
in.close();
s = str1.toString();
```

getting filenotfound exception. dont know why?

else give me some suggestion to pass username and  passwrod parameter to the url by code..

Comment: Does it help to close the output stream only after you read from the input stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTTPClient offers a much simpler way to access http resources, when all you want to do is fetch the repsonse body:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://domain.com/path?var1=bla&var2=foo");
HTTPResponse reponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: this code very useful. i can get the htmlsource. but not login with my parameter. how to set action class to the http response.

Comment: Are you trying to use basic authentication? Your could pass the username and password like this before issuing your request.

UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

Comment: before issuing your request in the sense before HttpGet. right?

Comment: can you edit ur answer with exact answer plz?? i still have a same problem.